# Reading GeoJSON-String from CSV as Geometry in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geojson, csv

I have a CSV which contains the geometry information as a GeoJSON string, e.g.

```
{ "type": "MultiLineString",
    "coordinates": [
        [[10, 10], [20, 20], [10, 40]],
        [[40, 40], [30, 30], [40, 20], [30, 10]]
    ]
}
```

which is just a text field.

I would like to display this geometry in QGIS 3. I could go via PostGIS and use [`ST_GeomFromGeoJSON`](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html), but would prefer a direct way, without adding my data to a PostGIS database first.

Unfortunately, virtual layers do not recognize this function and as expressions there only seem to be `geom_from_wkt()` and `geom_from_gml()`.

Is there a possibilty to read this GeoJSON-String as Geometry directly from a CSV column?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can retrieve the GeoJSON text in a Python object, you can execute the code below :

```py
# geoj is the string object that contains the GeoJSON
geoj = """
{ "type": "MultiLineString",
    "coordinates": [
        [[10, 10], [20, 20], [10, 40]],
        [[40, 40], [30, 30], [40, 20], [30, 10]]
    ]
}
"""
# PyQGIS has a parser class for JSON and GeoJSON
feats = QgsJsonUtils.stringToFeatureList(geoj, QgsFields(), None)
# if there are features in the list
if len(feats) > 0:
    # define the geometry type of the layer
    geom_type = feats[0].geometry().type()
    if geom_type == QgsWkbTypes.PointGeometry:
        geotype = "MultiPoint"
    elif geom_type == QgsWkbTypes.LineGeometry:
        geotype = "MultiLineString"
    elif geom_type == QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry:
        geotype = "MultiLinePolygon"
    else:
        print("geometry type not defined in the script")
    # create a new memory layer with the features
    vl = QgsVectorLayer(geotype, "geojson_layer", "memory")
    with edit(vl):
        vl.addFeatures(feats)
        vl.updateExtents()
    # add this brand new layer
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
else:
    print("no features found in the geoJSON")
```

Comment: I compared 3.4 and latest API, and they added a `QgsFields()` default value, so I made a little edit in my code.

Comment: I'm getting an AssertionError (assert self.layer.startEditing() AssertionError). This happens even if I'm applying layer.startEditing() before the 'with edit' block, and layer.commitChanges() after it.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [J. Monticolo's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/382615/107424) I have modified his script. The first one is for python console and the second one a processing algorithm.
Both will ignore features, that have an invalid GeoJSON-String as content.

Script for Python-Console:

```py
# Define settings:
source_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("mylayer")[0] # Define Source-layer
new_layer = QgsVectorLayer('MultiLineString', "new_geojson_layer", "memory") # Define new layer and its type
source_geojsonfield = 'geojsonstring' # Fieldname containing the GeoJSON

#####
# No Changes needed below #
#####

# Copy fields from old layer to new layer
source_fields = source_layer.fields()
new_layer_pr = new_layer.dataProvider()
new_layer.startEditing()
new_layer_pr.addAttributes(source_fields)
new_layer.commitChanges()

for feature in source_layer.getFeatures():
    # geoj is the string object that contains the GeoJSON
    geoj = feature.attributes()[source_fields.indexFromName(source_geojsonfield)]
    # PyQGIS has a parser class for JSON and GeoJSON
    geojfeats = QgsJsonUtils.stringToFeatureList(geoj, QgsFields(), None)
    # if there are features in the list
    if len(geojfeats) > 0:
        new_geom = geojfeats[0].geometry()
        with edit(new_layer):
            new_feat = QgsFeature(feature)
            new_feat.setGeometry(new_geom)
            new_layer.addFeature(new_feat)
            new_layer.updateExtents()
    else:
        print("No features found in the GeoJSON or no valid GeoJSON-String")

# add this brand new layer
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(new_layer)
```

Script for Processing-Tool:

*The selection of the target-wkb-type in the processing tool is not an optimal implementation... if you know a better solution, feel free to edit it*

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QVariant
from qgis.core import (QgsJsonUtils, QgsField, QgsFeature, QgsProcessing, QgsExpression, QgsGeometry, QgsPoint, QgsFields, QgsWkbTypes,
                       QgsFeatureSink, QgsFeatureRequest, QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink, QgsProcessingParameterCrs, QgsProcessingParameterField, QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource, QgsProcessingParameterEnum, QgsProcessingParameterString, QgsProcessingParameterNumber)

class GeometryLayerFromGeojsonStringField(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    SOURCE_LYR = 'SOURCE_LYR'
    GEOJSON_FIELD = 'GEOJSON_FIELD'
    #GEOMETRYTYPE_STRING = 'GEOMETRYTYPE_STRING'
    GEOMETRYTYPE_ENUM = 'GEOMETRYTYPE_ENUM'
    CRS = 'CRS'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'
    

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):  
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.SOURCE_LYR, self.tr('Source'), [QgsProcessing.TypeMapLayer])) # Take any source layer, unfortunately no-geometry layers will not be available...
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterField(
                self.GEOJSON_FIELD, self.tr('Field containing the GeoJSON as string'),'GeoJSON','SOURCE_LYR', 1)) # Choose the field containing the GeoJSON as string
        #self.addParameter(
        #    QgsProcessingParameterNumber(
        #        self.GEOMETRYTYPE_STRING, self.tr('Geometry type of the target layer / of the GeoJSON content as number (lookup at https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Wkb/QgsWkbTypes.html)'),0,5)) # Unfortunately there is no WKB-Type-Input available...
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterEnum(
                self.GEOMETRYTYPE_ENUM, self.tr('Geometry type of the target layer / of the GeoJSON content'),
                ['Unknown','Point','LineString','Polygon','MultiPoint','MultiLineString','MultiPolygon','GeometryCollection','CircularString','CompoundCurve','CurvePolygon'],defaultValue=5)) # Only Works because these are ascending numerated in QGIS... NOT A GOOD SOLUTION!! But better than typing in a number by hand... see https://qgis.org/api/classQgsWkbTypes.html
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterCrs(
                self.CRS, self.tr('CRS of the target layer / of the GeoJSON content'),'EPSG:4326')) # CRS of the targetlayer
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
                self.OUTPUT, self.tr('new_geojson_layer'))) # Output

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        # Get Parameters and assign to variable to work with
        source_layer = self.parameterAsLayer(parameters, self.SOURCE_LYR, context)
        source_geojsonfield = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.GEOJSON_FIELD, context)
        #wkbgeometrytype = self.parameterAsInt(parameters, self.GEOMETRYTYPE_STRING, context)
        wkbgeometrytype_fromenum = self.parameterAsInt(parameters, self.GEOMETRYTYPE_ENUM, context)
        wkbgeometrytype = wkbgeometrytype_fromenum # testing assignment        
        crsgeometry = self.parameterAsCrs(parameters, self.CRS, context)
        
        total = 100.0 / source_layer.featureCount() if source_layer.featureCount() else 0 # Initialize progress for progressbar
        
        source_fields = source_layer.fields() # get all fields of the sourcelayer
        
        (sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(parameters, self.OUTPUT, context, source_fields, wkbgeometrytype, crsgeometry)
                                               
        for current, feature in enumerate(source_layer.getFeatures()): # iterate over source 
            # geoj is the string object that contains the GeoJSON
            geoj = feature.attributes()[source_fields.indexFromName(source_geojsonfield)]
            # PyQGIS has a parser class for JSON and GeoJSON
            geojfeats = QgsJsonUtils.stringToFeatureList(geoj, QgsFields(), None)
            # if there are features in the list
            if len(geojfeats) > 0:
                new_geom = geojfeats[0].geometry()
                new_feat = QgsFeature(feature)
                new_feat.setGeometry(new_geom)
                sink.addFeature(new_feat, QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert) # add feature to the output
            
            if feedback.isCanceled(): # Cancel algorithm if button is pressed
                break
            
            feedback.setProgress(int(current * total)) # Set Progress in Progressbar

        return {self.OUTPUT: dest_id} # Return result of algorithm



    def tr(self, string):
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    def createInstance(self):
        return GeometryLayerFromGeojsonStringField()

    def name(self):
        return 'GeometryLayerFromGeojsonStringField'

    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr('New Layer from GeoJSON String')

    def group(self):
        return self.tr('FROM GISSE')

    def groupId(self):
        return 'from_gisse'

    def shortHelpString(self):
        return self.tr('This Algorithm takes a source layer containing a GeoJSON as a String in a field and creates a copy of this layer with the geometry of this GeoJSON field')
```

Comment: For the Wkb type, why don't you use a Enum parameter ? https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Processing/QgsProcessingParameterEnum.html?highlight=qgsprocessingparameterenum

Comment: @J.Monticolo just done that, but its not a good solution as I need to rewrite the entire list. Was trying to solve it as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29503339/how-to-get-all-values-from-python-enum-class but getting `TypeError: 'sip.enumtype' object is not iterable` when trying to access `QgsWkbTypes.Type` like this.

Comment: Why don't you delete this parameter and guess the geometry type after `geojfeats` as I wrote it in my code ?

Comment: @J.Monticolo because I need to define the wkb-type when creating the output layer. If I would guess it, I'd either have to iterate over the source layer twice (one time before creating the output, and one time after creating it), or pick a random example in hope it is a valid one.

Comment: I think it's not the case, look at my code in my post, I just take the first feature after `geojfeats` and extract the geometry type.

Comment: And they are dirty methods to get types list with values : `[(eval(f"QgsWkbTypes.{i}"), i) for i in dir(QgsWkbTypes) if type(eval(f"QgsWkbTypes.{i}")) == QgsWkbTypes.Type]`

Answer (score 1):

As I am not allowed to comment I have to make an annotation answer and
just because it took me a while testing the answer and finding the problem:

There is no geotype = "MultiLinePolygon" rather should it be
geotype = "MultiPolygon"