# Read GeoJSON object in a CSV file column and transform it to geometry

Tags: geojson, geometry, geopandas, csv, transform

I have a column ('geo_shape') that contains GeoJSON  object type of linestring geometry and, so far, I didn't manage to read and transform it to a GeoPandas/shapefile type of geometry.

Here is  a way to do it with QGIS Python module: [Reading GeoJSON-String from CSV as Geometry in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/382613/reading-geojson-string-from-csv-as-geometry-in-qgis)

I have tried this method also : [CSV containing GeoJSON format geometries to DataFrame](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/359285/csv-containing-geojson-format-geometries-to-dataframe)

All I get is this **JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 12 (char 11)**
Which I didn't manage to solve yet.

Here how the data look like (it's a type 'object' not a proper dictionary):

```
{"coordinates": [[5.807033273966051, 43.19284592374117], [5.807314867862657, 43.192757356667016]], "type": "LineString"}
```

When trying this method: [CSV containing GeoJSON format geometries to DataFrame](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/359285/csv-containing-geojson-format-geometries-to-dataframe)

```
import ast

def parse_geom(geom_str):
    try:
        return shape(json.loads(geom_str))
    except (TypeError, AttributeError):  # Handle NaN and empty strings
        return None


df["geo_shape"] = df["geo_shape"].apply(parse_geom)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry="geo_shape")
gdf.head()
```

All I get is a None value :

[image]

I also tried this method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68820085/how-to-convert-geojson-to-shapely-polygon

geo: dict = df["geo_shape"]
linestring: LineString = shape(geo)

[image]

And this too: [How can I use GeoPandas to read a string containing GeoJSON content into a GeoDataFrame?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/420163/how-can-i-use-geopandas-to-read-a-string-containing-geojson-content-into-a-geoda)

gdf = gpd.read_file(df["geo_shape"], driver='GeoJSON')
gdf.head()

The result is this: **TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object**

Does anyone has an idea how to deal with it with GeoPandas and GeoJSON?

Comment: What code did you try?

Comment: [CSV containing GeoJSON format geometries to DataFrame](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/359285/csv-containing-geojson-format-geometries-to-dataframe)

Comment: @user2856 Already tried that one, and it's not working for me. I will retry it but I am kinda of new in geopandas, dataframe and so I am still struggeling with finding solution to my problems :)

Comment: Then to avoid your question getting closed, you should add your attempt and any errors/incorrect results to your question.

Comment: Oh okay, I'll try to update this

Comment: Q/A on GIS SE site are not intended only to solve problem of particular user, but be helpful resource for anybody with similar questions/problems. That's the reason question has to be complete in itself and include all relevant code as text, since outside links tend to get lost in time and also that there is no need to visit other sites to get complete picture of what the problem/question is. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Answer (score 0):

```
from shapely import Point
import json

def make_point(json_feature):
    dict_json = json.loads(json_feature)
    pnt = Point(dict_json['coordinates'][0][0],
                dict_json['coordinates'][0][1])

   return pnt

infra_gaz['new_pnt_geom'] = infra_gaz['geo_shape'].apply(
                   make_point, axis=1)
```

Can make shapely point with custom function and use apply to create new point column.

Comment: Thank you for answering but actually I am trying to create a LineString geometry with the "geo_shape" column. Is there a way to deal with that the way you propose to deal with the problem?

Comment: Yes instead of point would use LineString. The array like data would work so would want LineString(dict_json['coordinates'])

Comment: Ok thank you very much, I'll try and keep you updated!

Comment: Well it didn't quite work, in fact I have a nest dictionnary that is a type object... I will try to come up a solution, but so far I just dowloaded the same file geojson to deal with it.